# Php and Javascript slider issue

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a issue in slider for my php website
the slider is displaying all images from my database actually i want to limit it to 25
and second thing i want to echo other details which are in div tag and i am new to php so dont know how to display these details

```
 <ul class="flexiselDemo1">
 <?
        $query = "SELECT * FROM car_cardetail where approval=1 order by carid desc";
        $result = mysql_query($query);
        $num = mysql_num_rows($result);
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)){ 
        ?>
 <li>
<?
 echo "<a class='carimg11' id= 'carimg11' href= 'view_pic.php?carid=$row[carid]&useid=1' > <img src=\"upload/thumb/$row[carimg1]\" class='img-thumbnail'> </a>";
 }
 ?>
<div class="details">
    <h5>Skoda Yeti</h5>

    <p><?=$lb_price?> : 1000 </p>
    <p><?=$lb_year?> : 2006  </p>
    <p><?=$lb_model?> : Rapide</p>
    <p><?=$lb_mileage?> : 34432</p>
</div>
  </li>
</ul>
My javascript is

$('.flexiselDemo1').bxSlider({
 minSlides: 1,
 maxSlides: 8,
 slideWidth: 277,
 slideMargin: 10,
 pager:false,
 controls:true,
});
slider2=$('.flexiselDemo2').bxSlider({
 minSlides: 1,
 maxSlides: 8,
 slideWidth: 277,
 slideMargin: 10,
 pager:false,
 controls:true,
});
slider3=$('.flexiselDemo3').bxSlider({
 minSlides: 1,
 maxSlides: 8,
 slideWidth: 277,
 slideMargin: 10,
 pager:false,
 controls:true,
});
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
slider2.reloadSlider();
slider3.reloadSlider();
})
    $('.dropd').click(function() {
        $(this).find('.options').slideDown('fast');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        $(this).bind('mouseleave', function() {
            $(this).find('.options').slideUp('fast');
            $(this).removeClass('active');
        });
```

Comment: It is to do with your db query then. Use the query "SELECT * FROM car_cardetail where approval=1 order by carid desc LIMIT 25". You have a risk of loosing those images if the images are more than 25.

Comment: i want to echo these things also from database like image       <div class="details">
    <h5>Skoda Yeti</h5>

    <p><?=$lb_price?> : 1000 </p>
    <p><?=$lb_year?> : 2006  </p>
    <p><?=$lb_model?> : Rapide</p>
    <p><?=$lb_mileage?> : 34432</p>
</div>
  </li>
</ul>

Comment: Could you mention if these details are there in the same table car_cardetail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your first question, use the below query

```
SELECT * FROM car_cardetail where approval=1 order by carid desc LIMIT 25
```

For your second question, use the below code based on the column in your database table.
Use $row based on the columns in your table Assuming that the details are available in the database table car_cardetail.

```
<div class="details">
   <h5><?php echo $row[0]; ?></h5> // Use this $row based on the columns in your table Assuming that the details are available in the database table car_cardetail.
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM car_cardetail where approval=1 order by carid desc LIMIT 25";
```

use this query limit 25 from database

Comment: i want to echo these things also from database like image       <div class="details">
    <h5>Skoda Yeti</h5>

    <p><?=$lb_price?> : 1000 </p>
    <p><?=$lb_year?> : 2006  </p>
    <p><?=$lb_model?> : Rapide</p>
    <p><?=$lb_mileage?> : 34432</p>
</div>
  </li>
</ul>

Comment: add this code in while loop and echo the value from db

Answer (score 0):

1. Use LIMIT 25 in your Select function to limit images to 25.

`$query = "SELECT * FROM car_cardetail where approval=1 order by carid desc LIMIT 25";`

2. You should have all this informations in your $row in while. for example for lb_price field it should be $row['lb_rpice'].

Inside while:

```
$row['lb_price'].
```

To see this array just make:

```
var_dump($row)
```

it should be more clear for you then.

Comment: i want to echo these things also from database like image       <div class="details">
    <h5>Skoda Yeti</h5>

    <p><?=$lb_price?> : 1000 </p>
    <p><?=$lb_year?> : 2006  </p>
    <p><?=$lb_model?> : Rapide</p>
    <p><?=$lb_mileage?> : 34432</p>
</div>
  </li>
</ul>

Comment: You should have all this informations in your $row in while. for example for lb_price field it should be $row['lb_rpice'].